# How to Change BundleVersion to four non-negative integers in iOS

Tags: ios, app-store

Now My BundleVersion is like 1.3.1, now I want to change it to 1.3.1.1, can someone tell me how to do it?

update: I searched the solution in the internet , and some one said adding an new key in plist 'sys-clientVersion',and set it to 1.3.1.1 . I tried that way but than the Xcode gave me an error:"ERROR ITMS-90060 : This bundle is invalid . The value of key CFBundleShortVersionString 1.3.1.1 in the info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non - negative integers".'

This is my info.plist :

[image]

so , the 'Bundle versions string' equal to 'Version' in Identity, and the 'Bundle version' equal to 'Build' , and 'sys-clientVersion' is what i want show in app store , right~?

Comment: Yes, 'Bundle versions string , short' is equal to "CFBundleShortVersionString" in info.plist source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's super easy go the iTunesConnect select your app, version and scroll down to **General App Information** there is a textfield under App Store Icon, it contains the version number say 1.3.1 you can change it to 1.3.1.1. Have a look at the following image.

[image]

P.S keep in mind that the version number should be incremented from previous one.

**Edit:**

For Xcode Error: `ERROR ITMS-90060` while submitting the app check your "Bundle versions string, short" in info.plist file by right-clicking on it and open it as source-code. Search for CFBundleShortVersionString and confirm that the value shouldn't contain any space or non-integers.

Comment: thanks , you mean , first I upload my new version as usual like 1.3.1 , than , I go to iTunesConnection , change the version manually。Is there an solution to change the version digit in project?  I search it in the net , and some says just add an new key 'sys-clientVersion',and set it to 1.3.1.1 . I tried that way but the Xcode gave me an error:"ERROR ITMS-90060 : This bundle is invalid . The value of key CFBundleShortVersionString 1.3.1.1 in the info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non - negative integers".

Comment: In Xcode, right click on info.plist and select Open As -> source code. Search for CFBundleShortVersionString and check that does it contains any space? it should be <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
 <string>1.3.1.1</string>

Comment: this is the key in my plist:<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
 <string>1.0</string> , no any space .  it is strange , because my current version is not 1.0 , should i change it to 1.8.4.1? this is the bundleVersion what i want .

Comment: If problem still exist then do check the top answers on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287059/cfbundleshortversionstring-must-be-a-period-separated-list-of-most-three-non-neg

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by just adding sys-clientVersion key , and set your wanted version to the key (e.g 1.1.1.0). The most importent point is , just increase your current Version and Build ( in General - Identity) e.g 1.0.0->1.1.0.  as normally . the sys-clientVersion now is showing in app store. and unrelated with Version or Build.